# Error 'map' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, linux, compiler-errors

Trying to finish up a personal project of mine, and I'm stuck on this issue.  I am  making a 2d game, and thought I had it setup well, but I get back an error, that basically says one of my variables is not declared in numerous scopes.  Here is my code, trying to make a simple 2d game, trying to compile and run in Linux.

Errors specifically state:

> project.cpp:52:7:  error: 'map' was not declared in this scope

```
 if(map[y2][x] == '^') {


#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

cout << "Help the Brave adventurer, &, find his way through the maze, to reach the Treasure, $$!"

char map[17][21] = {                
    "Use W,A,S,D to move"
    "Press X to end game"   
    "####################",
    "# & ##      ##  # ^#",
    "#   ##^        ^# ^#",
    "#   ##      ## ^#  #",
    "#  ^##     ^##     #",
    "#           ##  #^ #",
    "#^          #####  #",
    "#   ##         ^#  #",
    "#   ##^^    #^  #  #",
    "# ^^##  #####   #  #",
    "#   ##  #     ^    #",
    "#   ##  #^ ^#   #  #",
    "#   ##^        ^#$$#",
    "####################",

};

int x = 1;      
int y = 1;      
int hp = 5;

bool game_run = true;

int main ()
{
    while(game_run == true) {   
        system("clear");        
        for(int showMap=0; showMap<17; showMap++) {
            cout << map[showMap]
        }
        system("pause > nul");   

        if(cin.get() == 's'){           
            int y2 = y+1;
            if(map[y2][x] == ' ') { 
                map[y][x] = ' ';
                y++; 
                map[y][x] = '&';    
            }
            if(map[y2][x] == '^') {
                hp--;
            }
        }
        if(cin.get() == 'w'){           
            int y2 = y-1;
            if(map[y2][x] == ' ') {     
                map[y][x] = ' ';
                y--;                                        
                map[y][x] = '&';
            }
            if(map[y2][x] == '^') {
                hp--;
            }   
        }
        if(cin.get() == 'd'){
            int x2 = x+1;
            if(map[y][x2] == ' ') {
                map[y][x] = ' ';
                x++;
                map[y][x] = '&';
            }
            if(map[y][x2] == '^') {
                hp--;
            }
        }
        if(cin.get() == 'a'){
            int x2 = x-1;
            if(map[y][x2] == ' ') {
                map[y][x] = ' ';
                x--;
                map[y][x] = '&';
            }
            if(map[y][x2] == '^') {
                hp--;
                cout << "You have run into spikes!!!  Health has been decreased by 1...";
            }
        }
        if(cin.get() == 'x'){
            game_run = false;
        }
        if(hp == 0) {
            game_run = false;
            cout << "The hero has died.... game over... :(";
        }
    }   

    system("clear");
    cout << "Game Over";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is that "if(map[y2][x] == '^') {" in the beginning ?

Comment: Don't use `using namespace std`. This is really harmful, as in this case it hides your `map` variable.

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to rename the variable to something other than "`map`", since it is  also represent the `std::map`.
2. And is that first line "`if(map[y2][x] == '^') {`" a typo ?
3. I think you have to move this
   `cout << "Help the Brave adventurer, &, find his way through the maze, to reach the Treasure, $$!"` into main()

Comment: Ok, I renamed it to a diff variable name other than map, since the conflictions with STD.

Also, moved the "Help the brave adventurer..."  into main.


Now my main question is, I was able to get this working on windows, obviously with some changes in code, can you refer me to good material to get the movement to respond to keystrokes?  I was using arrow keys to move in windows, but since I could not find a great alternative to AsyncKey, I was trying to assign movement to W,A,S,D, but after compiling and running, it is not responsive.

Comment: @user3577531 I think you better to open a new question for that

Answer (score 1):

Considering  first line `if(map[y2][x] == '^') {` as a typo ,

Following needs to be fixed , to at least compile and run**

First, `cout << "Help the Brave adventurer...` should be placed inside `main`

Second, fix following :

```
char map[17][21] = 
{               
       "Use W,A,S,D to move", // add comma
       "Press X to end game", // add comma
       // ....
} ;
```

<sup>****There seems to be logical errors too !** Don't ask all of them here please.</sup>

Comment: Thats what I am working on now.  I have been having trouble finding good reference material to help me understand how to assign movement to keys, so it updates the map.  I could get it to work in Windows, with Async, but having a hard time finding a comparable solution in Linux.

Comment: @user3577531 But this is not your question, right ? Asking in comment entirely a new question is never advised, and don't assume people to solve all syntactical and logical errors for you, thanks

Comment: Ok, sorry about that.  Im just trying to understand how to get this to work, transitioning from Windows to Linux

Comment: @user3577531 _"Im just trying to understand..."_ should be _"Im **now** trying to understand ..."_. Your current program won't compile on any platform, not sure how you did it on windows. You should now ask a new question, if you errors are resolved, thanks

Comment: This isnt what the program for windows looked like.  This is after many conversions/changes to attempt to get it to work on linux.  I am no pro, and I do not pretend to be.